# How can a probability densitiy be estimated based on the maximum entropy principle, with constraints in the order statistics?

Tags: density-function, entropy, order-statistics, density-estimation, maximum-entropy

Let's say we are given a sample $\{ z_i \}$, $i=1,2,\ldots,N$, such that each value $z_i$ corresponds to the minimum of $n$ random variables $x$, i.e.,  $z = \min \{ x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_n \}$.

**The question is:** how can we estimate the probability density $P(x\mid \{ z_i \},n)$ of $x$ given the sample $\{ z_i \}$ and $n$?

**Note:** of course, we could use elementary order statistics and use the empirical distribution function $F_z$ of $z$ and do $F_x = 1-(1-F_z)^{1/n}$ to obtain the CDF of $x$. However, since $z$ is the minimum of a sample of $x$, based on $\{ z_i \}$ we cannot reconstruct the right tail of the density, $P(x \rightarrow\infty)$. For this reason, it makes sense to look for the maximum entropy estimation of the density $P(x\mid\{ z_i \},n)$, under the constraint that we know the statistics of minimums given by the sample $\{ z_i \}$.

Comment: Very interesting question! My money would be on the guess that the tail of $x$ is exponential, just like in the ME distribution of $x$ if the only constraint is that $\mathrm{E}[x]$ is given.